For a pre-test/post-test setting should I use the raw score, the scaled score, or the standard score to perform Student's t-test?
I'm a bit lost. I'm working on a project that seeks to evaluate the effectiveness of an educational intervention. To do this, a standardized test is applied before and after the intervention with the same group (pre-test/post-test). The sample is small, 35 individuals. The thing is that the test has three types of scores: raw score, scaled score, and standard score (depending on the age of the students). I plan to do a Shapiro-Wilk test to assess the normality of the data. If the distribution is normal, I would use Student's t-test to evaluate the effectiveness of the intervention, but I am not sure what score I would use: the raw score, the scaled score, or the standard score? Thank you

What exactly do you mean by scaled and standard? An additive and/or multiplicative shift won't affect the outcome of a t-test at all. With the usual scaling operation, you'll get the exact same result whether you scale or not.

Linear scalings won't affect how close any distribution is to normal. Some rescalings will automatically imply the same variance for each group. The over-arching question, simple to state but harder to think through, is what do you want to compare precisely?

Do you have the results from the pre-test? If you plot the raw, scaled and standard scores against each other, for example by using pairs() in R, you will get some information on how they relate to each other.

This may not be a complete answer to the question asked (in part because a full answer would require us to understand what is meant by "raw score, scaled score, and standard score (depending on the age of the students)". I will venture that a "raw score" is just the score on the test (e.g. test had a total of 73 points on offer, and the raw score is between 0 and 73). I will also venture that a "scaled score" is probably that same raw score, but now scaled, e.g. from 0 to 100 (i.e. to get percentiles). But I admit that I have no clue what a "standard score" is . So I will just provide some observations (which would not fit in comments).
The comment "depending on the age of the students" is a bit concerning; does it imply that some students, of a certain age, have 1 type of score, while others have another type? Then there is no way to perform any aggregate comparison; that requires all scores for all subjects to be on the same scale.
The OP also says "I plan to do a Shapiro-Wilk test to assess the normality of the data". The question is "what data"? If the data tested for normality is both the pre and post scores, then that is incorrect. What may (perhaps) need to be tested is the difference of scores (post-pre); that needs to be "not too non-normal" (i.e. no severe skew). Particularly because, with 35 subjects, the CLT will help significantly, unless the skewness is substantial.
As has been explained by other contributors, as long as the transformations (to go from raw, to scaled to standard) are linear, and the same for both pre and post scores, you will get exactly the same p-values for all 3 types of scores. But if the transformations are not linear, or are linear but different for pre and post, or for different age groups, then all bets are off; you will not be able to get any valid result.
Hence, I would use the raw score, compute the differences (post-pre) on the raw scores, check that it is not too "non-normal", trust the CLT, and perform a 1-sample t, on the differences. If after that, you want to express the detected effect (average score difference) as a scaled or standard score, then transform that effect. Much safer, and simpler.
One of the tags for the question was "Wilcoxon Sign Rank Test" (aka WSRt). There is no other detail in the question, but my guess is that, if the normality test were to "fail", then the OP intends to instead run a non-parametric test, specifically the WSRt. But, in spite of what (too) many textbooks, sites, etc. say, it is not a test of the median, but a test of the pseudomedian (the median of all possible paired averages from the sample). The WSRt becomes a test of the median, iff the sample comes from a symmetric distribution. But if the distribution is symmetric, it might as well be normal, and the CLT will kick in with as few as 4 or 5 observations; so with a sample size of 35, you can certainly use a paired t-test with symmetric data. And if it is not coming from a symmetric distribution, good luck trying to convince your audience that, because the pseudo-median is >0, the educational intervention was effective. Instead, run a true median test, Mood's median test.

Having some experience with standardised tests, I can have a guess at what a standard score is. If you give the same test to e.g. grades 8, 9 and 10, you expect students in 10th grade to get a higher score than students in 8th grade. If you want to compare across grades it will be more informative to have a score that rates the students compared to what they are expected to get. The test provider will have some empirics that tell them what the appropriate transformation will be, and this will often change between tests.

@jginestet, thank you for your kind and detailed answer. Your assumptions are correct and you have cleared up many doubts. Considering your indications, I have performed the Shapiro-Wilk test on the differences:  ShapiroResult (statistic=0.873283 pvalue=0.000412) and Kursotis: -0.9621838355871746
Skewness: -0.1801222779063587, so the distribution of the differences is platykurtic with a slight asymmetry. Taking this into account and what you have mentioned,  would you still  recommend to perform a 1-sample t, on the differences?

@Wonderee, yes I would still run a t-test (skewness and kurtosis are "mild", and 35 is "large enough").

@AkselA, thanks for the comment on "standard score". Then I definitively would stay with raw scores (since this is a paired test situation - same subjects pre and post-, the difference of scores is already "standardized").

Simulating some data in R, if you create a normally distributed variable, z-score transform it with scale(), or add some linear scaling, they will all produce the same shaped distribution:
#### Setup Parameters ####
set.seed(123)
n <- 100
mu <- 100
sd <- 10

#### Simulate Data ####
x.raw <- rnorm(n,mu,sd)
x.std <- scale(x.raw)
x.scale <- x.raw + 10

#### Plot Data ####
par(mfrow = c(1,3))
plot(density(x.raw), main = "Raw X")
plot(density(x.std), main = "Standardized X")
plot(density(x.scale), main = "Scaled X")

As shown below:

Running Shapiro tests on all three will give identical results:
#### Shapiros ####
shapiro.test(x.raw)
shapiro.test(x.std)
shapiro.test(x.scale)

As seen below:
> shapiro.test(x.raw)

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  x.raw
W = 0.98395, p-value = 0.2661

> shapiro.test(x.std)

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  x.std
W = 0.98395, p-value = 0.2661

> shapiro.test(x.scale)

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  x.scale
W = 0.98395, p-value = 0.2661

However, I advise against z-score transforming your variables for both time points and then running a t-test on them. This is because by definition you will get two distributions with a mean of zero and a standard deviation of one. So there will be no mean difference on the test, as shown below, where even distributions with much larger raw means will be reduced to no difference via z-scores:
#### Z-Score Transformed Test ####
z1 <- scale(rnorm(n, mu, sd))
z2 <- scale(rnorm(n, mean = 1000, sd = 100)) # arbitrarily large difference
t.test(z1, z2, paired = T)

Results give $p = 1$ and a mean difference that is essentially zero (note that the -5.927051e-16 here is scientific notation and isn't exactly zero because of floating point precision in R):
    Paired t-test

data:  z1 and z2
t = -4.0617e-15, df = 99, p-value = 1
alternative hypothesis: true mean difference is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.2895451  0.2895451
sample estimates:
mean difference 
  -5.927051e-16 


(+1) -- especially for making clear that if scaling means reduction of each group to have mean 0 and SD 1, then a later t test is utterly futile, as you've thrown away the information on different means and SDs that you need to feed to the test.
